# Can multiple 'OR' statements be combined if they have the same condition?

Tags: sql, count, aggregate-functions

I have the below OR statement with each column = 1 as the condition. Is there a shorter way of doing this? I have tried HAVING and IN but neither worked.

[image]

```sql
(count(distinct case when (fiscal_mth_idnt_june21 = 1 or fiscal_mth_idnt_july21 = 1 or fiscal_mth_idnt_august21 = 1) then contact_key end)) / sum(fiscal_mth_idnt_may21)*100 as within_three_months
```

is the main code I am interested in.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: What are the valid values for these month columns (i.e. fiscal_mth_idnt_june21 / fiscal_mth_idnt_july21 / fiscal_mth_idnt_august21). By any change does these columns hold only 1 or 0 ? or can they have any other values?

Answer (score 0):

The boolean expression:

```
fiscal_mth_idnt_june21 = 1 or fiscal_mth_idnt_july21 = 1 or fiscal_mth_idnt_august21 = 1
```

is equivalent to:

```
1 IN (fiscal_mth_idnt_june21, fiscal_mth_idnt_july21, fiscal_mth_idnt_august21)
```